# Unity - Blender models/animations showing gaps

Tags: unity, models, blender, normals

As part of a college project, a member of my group has made some simple chests with an open animation. Importing these into Unity though, I instantly noticed there were gaps where the faces should be. After a bit of experimenting, I figured it was because the Normals were facing the wrong way. The outside seemed fixed, but faces were missing when the chest opens during its animation. I'm guessing the inside of the chest will need another layer of faces with the Normals facing the right way...? Though surely this would means having doubles...?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put two faces with inverted normals instead, you have to use a **Double Sided Shader** in unity to show the backfaces too. if it's a custom shader, you can write `Cull Off` in your shader code, if not, you can download one from asset store or google.

You can also make your shader double sided in shader graph like shown in the following image:

[image]

There is a `Two Sided` toggle field in shader settings.

Comment: Okay, disregarding the Double Sided Shader for the moment, what would be the best thing to do in Blender to sort the issue out?

Comment: You can add faces manually inside the object but with a little movement so they won't be intersecting each other, or you can use solidify modifier to add width to your faces but these are not recommended.

Comment: The best way would be the double-sided shader

Comment: You're using unity 2019 so you can use shader graph to create your shaders, and there is an option there to make your shader double-sided without needing any code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into the Double Sided Shader. Thanks. :)

Comment: You're very welcome, my friend.

Comment: I've looked around a bit, but I can't find any tutorials on how you actually make double sided shaders using Shader Graph. :-\